# Plot of a domain in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to plot the following domain in the complex plane:

$\lbrace x\in\mathbb{C}|\: |x^{2}-1|<r\rbrace$

for some $r>1$.

I know that in general to take a square root of a complex number $z$ one would have to go to polar coordinates and the get $\sqrt{z}=r^{1/2}\exp (i\theta/2)$.

How do I proceed in taking a "square root of a disk"? in the sense that I can also rewrite it as $\lbrace \sqrt{w}|\: |w-1|<r\rbrace$. What kind of geometrical object is it? Still a disk?

(it's not a homework question, I'm just curious)

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is this square root of a disk in relation to the set you have given?

Comment: well, my question is, geometrically what is the set of all $x\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|x^{2}-1|<r$?

Comment: @BoZenKhaa I agree it was a bit vague. Just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $x=u+iv:$
$$
\sqrt{(u^2-v^2-1)^2+(2uv)^2}=|u^2-v^2-1+2uvi|=|x^2-1|<r.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but from what I understand this is just a different algebraic way of writing my inequality using $x=u+iv$. But what kind of object is the inequality? Is it a disk? Half a disk? @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla

Comment: The border is $(u^2-v^2-1)^2+(2uv)^2=r^2$. Expand and find $v$ as function of $u$ (you can, is a biquadratic equation).

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla. Now the two curves $v(u)$ I got are $v^{2}=-1-u^{2}+\sqrt{4u^{2}+r^{2}}$ (the other two roots don't exist). I then plotted it in Mathematica for $r=2.5$ and $u$ between -2 and 2. Got something like "oval shape". However, by the structure of the equation, that's clearly not an ellipse, right? So what would be the correct name for the shape?

Comment: I think (I have not done the calculations) that is a Cassini Oval: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval.